# iOS dynamic UI in simple terms?

Tags: ios, swift

This may be too basic or require rephrasing. I am in the process of learning Swift and iOS programming and have developed a basic application that runs successfully on my iPhone 5. The app consists of a label, a button, and a UIImageView. It looks the way I want it to on my iPhone 5.

I figured most of this out by just playing around and so I am creating all these elements programatically. The code looks like this:

```
let banner = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 300.0, height: 75.0))
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 45, y: 75, width: 235.0, height: 60.0))
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 22, y: 150, width: 280.0, height: 410.0))
```

And then I configure them in `viewDidLoad` to make them show stuff.

Now the question...how to I make them all the right size when running on different devices? I can load up the app on my iPad Mini but it's all scrunched over to the left of the view. So I need to do some kind of dynamic layout but not sure where to start.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than creating the view sizes explicitly with `initWithFrame:` constructors, you can programmatically create and `NSLayoutConstraints` to your views to automatically layout your views, the same as if you used Auto Layout with the Interface Builder. See Apple's [Auto Layout Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html) for more details.

Comment: Also, look at the Ray Wenderlich tutorial for Autolayout or watch the 2013 WWDC Autolayout video.